# Prove $\int_{0}^{1} \left|\frac {f^{''}(x)}{f(x)}\right|\, dx \geq 4$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, inequality, integral-inequality

I find an interesting theorem,but have no idea to prove it.

$f(x) \in C^2[0,1]$ and $f(0)=f(1)=0$ , $f(x) \not = 0 \     \ ,  x\in (0,1) $

Prove that  if $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} \left|\frac {f^{''}(x)}{f(x)}\right| dx$ exists, $$\int_{0}^{1} \left|\frac {f^{''}(x)}{f(x)}\right| dx \geq 4$$

It is a problem for fun. If anyone knows how to do, plz tell me, not just vote " It's useless".

---

**Edit:** I submit a proof in [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118148/prove-int-01-left-fracfxfx-right-dx-geq4). And there are more two excellent answers.

Comment: What about $f(x)=x(x-1)$ isn't that a counterexample?

Comment: @ TheOscillator I think it is not a counter example. As the improper integral does not converge for your function

Comment: Could you explain the notation $C^2[0,1]$?

Comment: 2nd order continuously differentiable

Comment: @Panja.S. I have been wondering about this statement, continuously differentiable.  Is it my understanding or what, a function is differentiable only if it is continuous on the interval. Then why say continuously differentiable?

Comment: @satish ramanathan .$C^2$ means that $f^{''}(x)$ is continuous but may not be differentible.

Comment: @Syuizen:, but you have not answered my question which is $f^{"}(x)$ is differentiable only if it is continuous. The opposite is implicit and someone to say it is continuously differentiable is redundant. Might as well say differentiable.  Am I not getting it?

Comment: @satish ramanathan .Oh,I see.In mathematics, $f(x)$ is " n-th order  continuously differentiable " if and only if $f^{(n)}(x)$ exists and is continuous. Thus this description is not redundant, "differentiable" is for $f(x)$ , "continuously" is for n-times derivative of $f(x)$.

Comment: sturm comparison theorem amy have something to do with this problem.

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118148/prove-int-01-left-fracfxfx-right-dx-geq4